# Move files to folder with the same first 5 characters in Applescript

Tags: macos, file, applescript, directory

Suppose I have the following files in folder "A":

*"AAAAA 1x1", "AAAAA 1x2", "BBBBB 1x1", "BBBBB 1x2", "CCCCC 1x1", "CCCCC 1x2".*

And in folder "B", I have the following folders:

*"AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC".*

What I'd like to do is move all the "AAAAA" files in folder "A", to folder "AAAAA" in folder "B", "BBBBB" files to folder "BBBBB", and so on.

How would I do this using Apple Script?

Answer (score 1):

Try running a command like this in Terminal:

```
for f in A/*; do echo mv "$f" B/${f:2:5}; done
```

Remove `echo` to actually move the files.

Comment: OP - just in case you don't know - walk this way to test this code: 1. open Terminal.app. 2. Type "cd " (without quotes but with a space-character - "cd" means "change directory"). Now drag the folder that contains folder A and folder B into the terminal-window. Terminal will paste the path right into it. 3. Press Enter. Your working directory is now set to the right point where you can test Lauri's line which would be step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set folderA to "/Users/Joao/Desktop/A"
set folderB to "/Users/Joao/Desktop/B"

tell application "System Events"
    set subFolders to folders of (folder folderB)
    repeat with subfolderB in subFolders
        move (files of folder folderA whose name starts with (name of subfolderB)) to (path of subfolderB)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code (thanks to some fine folks at MacScripter):

```
set sourceFolder to alias "SSD:Users:JPCanaverde:Documents:A"
set destinationFolder to alias "SSD:Users:JPCanaverde:Documents:B"
tell application "Finder"
   repeat with aFolder in (get folders of destinationFolder)
       set folderName to name of aFolder
       set filesToMove to (files of sourceFolder whose name begins with folderName)
       move filesToMove to (contents of aFolder)
   end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: BTW I added a comment to Lauri's answer in case you never used Terminal.app but want to try that one-liner. I bet it's very fast.

Comment: You should avoid using Finder when possible. This structure of this answer is very similar to my answer. However, my answer uses System Events which is faster and the recommended method.